# FOR loop optimization in R

Tags: r, loops

I have the following code that it taking forever to run on my 80k rows CBP table. Anyone could help me optimize my loop. Trying simply to find duplicates sharing the same values in certain (not all) columns, getting the number of duplicates there is and then returning the ids for each of the duplicates:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(CBP)){

    subs <- subset(CBP, CBP$Lower_Bound__c == CBP[row,"Lower_Bound__c"] & CBP$Price_Book__c == CBP[row,"Price_Book__c"] & CBP$Price__c == CBP[row,"Price__c"] & CBP$Product__c == CBP[row,"Product__c"] & CBP$Department__c == CBP[row,"Department__c"] & CBP$UOM__c == CBP[row,"UOM__c"] & CBP$Upper_Bound__c == CBP[row,"Upper_Bound__c"])

    if (nrow(subs)>1){
        CBP[row,]$dup <- nrow(subs)
        CBP[row,]$dupids <- paste(subs[,"Id"], collapse = ",")

    }
    print(row)

}
```

Comment: The best for loop optimization in R is to try to avoid them completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding your example. However, here's a simple approach with data.table that might work for your situation. You can create a variable (`nsame` in the example) that counts if the something is a duplicate by multiple variables (`var1` and `var2` in the example).  Then just grab the row index.

```
library(data.table)

# generate some example data
dt <- data.table(
    var1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
    var2 = c("a", "a", "z", "b", "y", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
    var3 = 1:9
)

# counter for each combination of var1-var2
dt[ , nsame := 1:.N, by=.(var1, var2)]

# duplicates are where the counter is > 1
which(dt$nsame > 1)
## 2 6 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
dupe_columns = c(
  "Lower_Bound__c", "Price_Book__c", "Price__c", "Product__c",
  "Department__c", "UOM__c", "Upper_Bound__c"
)

# which rows are duplicated
dupes = which(duplicated(CBP[, dupe_columns]) | duplicated(CBP[, dupe_columns], fromLast = TRUE))

# how many are there
length(dupes)

# IDs that are duplicated
CBP[dupes, "Id"]

# collapse Ids with duplicates by group:
aggregate(CBP$Id, by = CBP[dupe_columns], FUN = paste, collapse = ",")
```

If any of this doesn't work or you need more help, post 10-20 rows of sample data (use `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable!!!) so we can test and verify.

Subtle point, but I use `CBP[, dupe_columns]` in the `duplicated()` line because `duplicated()` will work the same whether we give it a data frame or a vector. `CBP[, dupe_columns]` will be a data frame if you have more than one column to check for dupes, but will be a vector if you give it a single column. However, when we get down to `aggregate` we need the `by` argument to be a `list` (like a data frame). So I use `CBP[dupe_columns]` (no comma) which will guarantee a data frame even if we are only checking a single column.